# On browser refresh, java method in JSP scriptlet is getting called

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have a requirement where on clicking a button, I have to empty the text area, which is populated from a file, and need to empty the file contents also.

My jsp page looks like this

```
<%@page import="com.hcentive.rule.DisplayLog"%>
<%@ page import="java.lang.*" import="java.util.Scanner"  
    import="java.io.FileReader" import="java.net.*"%>  

<%  
DisplayLog log = new DisplayLog();  
log.display();  
%>  

<html>   
    <body>  
     <script>
        function validate() {
           alert("clear clicked");
           document.getElementById("rule").value = "";
           <%
                log.clear(); 
           %>
        }
        </script>   
      <br><br>
        <FORM>
            <textarea rows="20" cols="162" wrap="off" id="rule" ><%=log.getFileOutput()%></textarea>  
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="validate();" >
        </FORM>  
    </body> 
</html>
```

In above code, **DisplayLog** is a java class. **display** method is used to read file contents and write in the text area and **clear** method is used to empty the file contents.

It is working fine when i click the clear button it empties the text area.The problem that i am facing is that on browser refresh, `log.clear()` is also getting called which i don't understand.

Please someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the call to log.clear is in a JavaScript function which is not being invoked is irrelevant here. When the page is rendered on refresh, all the scriptlets are evaluated, including this one. It is probably appropriate to clear the file contents when you submit the form rather than when the user clears the form. However if you do want to do it when the user clears the form then you could use AJAX to call out to the server and clear the log there.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should avoid using scriplets in JSP.

Second, instead use Ajax :

1. Create a servlet that can do the clearing part for the file
2. Use ajax in the `onClick` of your button and make a call to the
   servlet. Then the servlet will clear up the content on server side.